# Converting an output in Cell class type to matrix in Matlab R2016a

Tags: matlab

In one of the Matlab programs, I have declared B as:

```
B={};
```

and in the course of the program, the outputs are stored in B like this:

```
Columns 1 through 13

    'odd'    'even'    'odd'    'even'    'odd'    'even'    'odd'    'even'    'odd'    'even'    'odd'    'even'    'odd'

  Columns 14 through 16

    'even'    'odd'    'even'
```

And the type of this output is Cell
I would like to make it in a 4x4 matrix so that output shows like

```
odd even odd even
odd ...  ... ...
...
...
```

Would you please suggest the way of this conversion?

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this yourself?

Comment: I suggest you start using `logical` values (i.e. `true` and `false`).

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function:

```
B = reshape(B, 4, 4)
```

If you want to be able to use this with any other multiple of for elements, use `[]` to have the number of rows computed automatically:

```
B = reshape(B, [], 4)
```